# CSS3 animation weird movement in tablet/mobile

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've built some CSS animations with keyframes for a Demoproject I'm working on. I'm just using fadeIn, fadeOut, slideInLeft and slideOutLeft and they all work as expected in desktop mode.

But when I come down to tablet/mobile versions the slideInLeft animation gets an unexpected movement in the end of the animation. Something like a zoom effect. I've been pulling my hair for a while with this. The expected movement is a straight horizontal line from right to left.

My demo project is located at [this address](http://mideye.systemdrift.se). It's after you've clicked the first button and the second page slides in that has the bug. If you refresh the page the animation acts as expected.

**Edit**

**My animations:**

```
@keyframes slideInLeft {
    0% { left: 130%; }

    100% { left: 30%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
    0% { left: 130%; }

    100% { left: 30%; }
}



@media (min-width: 768px) {
    @keyframes slideInLeft {
        0% { left: 130%; }

        100% { left: 0; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
        0% { left: 130%; }

        100% { left: 0; }
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    @keyframes slideInLeft {
        0% { left: 130%; }

        100% { left: 10%; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
        0% { left: 130%; }

        100% { left: 10%; }
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    @keyframes slideInLeft {
        0% { left: 130%; }

        100% { left: 30%; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft {
        0% { left: 130%; }

        100% { left: 30%; }
    }
}

.slideInLeft {
    position: absolute !important;
    -webkit-animation: slideInLeft 2s;
    -moz-animation: slideInLeft 2s;
    -ms-animation: slideInLeft 2s;
    -o-animation: slideInLeft 2s;
    animation: slideInLeft 2s;
}
```

**Animated element**

```
.container {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 30%;
/*transform: translateX(-100%);*/
-webkit-transform: translateY(-60%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-60%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-60%);
-o-transform: translateY(-60%);
transform: translateY(-60%);
width: 40%;
display: block;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML Structure**

```
<div id="container" class="container slideInLeft">
    <div>
        <h1>
            Deactivation
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
            Enter your activated phone number in international format (e.g. +467012345678)
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="text" id="msisdn" />
    </div>
    <div id="loader" class="la-ball-scale-ripple-multiple la-2x spinner">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dots has-input">
        <ul id="bullet-list">
            <li class="blank"></li>
            <li class="selected"></li>
            <li class="blank"></li>
            <li class="blank"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <a href="#" class="button inactive" id="send-button">DEACTIVATE NUMBER</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful if you could post the relevant parts of your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that making the container "relative" both in regular css and animation class wolud do the job for you :)

Good luck!